# PHP - SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't property 'xxxx'

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm receiving this error while trying to do a SOAP request with PHP.  I can't for the life of me figure out why since the object is in the array.  I've looked at the dozen or so errors here on SO and can't come up with the solution.  Thanks in advance.

**Error:**

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object hasn't 'Pieces' property in /home/content/html/rr.php:43
Stack trace:
#0 /home/content/html/rr.php(63): SoapClient->__call('RateQuote', Array)
#1 /home/content/html/rr.php(63): SoapClient->RateQuote(Array)
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home//html/rr.php on line 43
```

**Offending line**:  `$return = $client->RateQuote(array('request'=>$params));`

**Array print_r($params):**

```
Array
(
    [QuoteRequest] => Array
        (
            [Pieces] => 0
            [ShipDate] => 2014-09-19
        )

)
```

**Var dump:**

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(50) "RateQuoteResponse RateQuote(RateQuote $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(77) "RateQuoteByAccountResponse RateQuoteByAccount(RateQuoteByAccount $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(107) "RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalResponse RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal(RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(50) "RateQuoteResponse RateQuote(RateQuote $parameters)"
  [4]=>
  string(77) "RateQuoteByAccountResponse RateQuoteByAccount(RateQuoteByAccount $parameters)"
  [5]=>
  string(107) "RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalResponse RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal(RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal $parameters)"
}
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php


$wsdlURL = "https://webservices.example.com/rating/quote.asmx?wsdl";

$username = "user";
$password = "pass";


            //Prepare SoapHeader parameters 
            $cred = array( 
                'UserName'      => $username, 
                'Password'  => $password,
                'Site' => ''
            );

            $params = array (
                'location' => "https://webservices.example.com/ratequote",
                'uri' => "https://webservices.example.com/",
                'trace' => "1",
                'exceptions' => "true"
            );

            $client = new SoapClient($wsdlURL,$params);
            $header = new SoapHeader($wsdlURL, 'AuthenticationHeader', $cred);
            $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

            $counter = 0;
            $params = array(
                          "QuoteRequest" => array(
                                "Pieces" => '0', 
                                "ShipDate" => '2014-09-19'

                            ),
                    ); 


                $return = $client->RateQuote(array('request'=>$params));


?>
```

**WDSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsdl:types>
    <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/">
      <s:element name="RateQuote">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:QuoteRequest"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="QuoteRequest">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginZip" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DestinationZip" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ShipmentDetails" type="tns:ArrayOfShipmentDetail"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginType" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentType" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PalletCount" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LinearFeet" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CubicFeet" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Pieces" type="s:int"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ServiceDeliveryOptions" type="tns:ArrayOfServiceOptions"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="COD" type="tns:CODFee"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Discount" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ListedConsigneeCity" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="InternalUse" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PalletPosition" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ShipDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfShipmentDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ShipmentDetail" nillable="true" type="tns:ShipmentDetail"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ShipmentDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ActualClass" type="s:double"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Weight" type="s:int"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfServiceOptions">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ServiceOptions" nillable="true" type="tns:ServiceOptions"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ServiceOptions">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ServiceCode" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CODFee">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Prepaid" type="s:boolean"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CODAmount" type="s:double"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RateQuoteResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RateQuoteResult" type="tns:QuoteResponse"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="QuoteResponse">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="QuoteNumber" type="s:int"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="NetCharge" type="s:double"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Customer" type="tns:CustomerInformation"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RoutingInfo" type="tns:RoutingInformation"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RateDetails" type="tns:ArrayOfQuoteDetail"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginType" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PaymentType" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CODAmount" type="s:double"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="ShipmentDate" type="s:dateTime"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CustomerCubicFoot" type="s:int"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="HawaiianRatedCubicFoot" type="s:int"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="CustomerInformation">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="AccountNumber" type="s:int"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Name" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address1" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Address2" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="City" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="State" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ZipCode" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="RoutingInformation">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DestinationState" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="DestinationZip" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginState" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginZip" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="EstimatedTransitDays" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="OriginTerminal" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="ArrayOfQuoteDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="QuoteDetail" nillable="true" type="tns:QuoteDetail"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:complexType name="QuoteDetail">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ActualClass" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RatedClass" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Charge" type="s:double"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Code" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Description" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Rate" type="s:double"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Weight" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="ExtraMessages" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="AuthenticationHeader" type="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
      <s:complexType name="AuthenticationHeader">
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="UserName" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Password" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Site" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
        <s:anyAttribute/>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RateQuoteByAccount">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:QuoteAccountRequest"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="QuoteAccountRequest">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="tns:QuoteRequest">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Account" type="s:int"/>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RateQuoteByAccountResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RateQuoteByAccountResult" type="tns:QuoteResponse"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:element name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="request" type="tns:QuoteAccountByTerminalRequest"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
      <s:complexType name="QuoteAccountByTerminalRequest">
        <s:complexContent mixed="false">
          <s:extension base="tns:QuoteAccountRequest">
            <s:sequence>
              <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TerminalCode" type="s:string"/>
            </s:sequence>
          </s:extension>
        </s:complexContent>
      </s:complexType>
      <s:element name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalResponse">
        <s:complexType>
          <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalResult" type="tns:QuoteResponse"/>
          </s:sequence>
        </s:complexType>
      </s:element>
    </s:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuote"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuoteResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteAuthenticationHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuoteByAccount"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuoteByAccountResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountAuthenticationHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalSoapIn">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalSoapOut">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalResponse"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalAuthenticationHeader">
    <wsdl:part name="AuthenticationHeader" element="tns:AuthenticationHeader"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="RateQuoteSoap">
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuote">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This method sends back a rate quote from the Road Runner Transportation Services System</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RateQuoteSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RateQuoteSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccount">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This method sends back a rate quote from the Road Runner Transportation Services System</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal">
      <wsdl:documentation xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">This method sends back a rate quote from the Road Runner Transportation Services System</wsdl:documentation>
      <wsdl:input message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalSoapIn"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalSoapOut"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="RateQuoteSoap" type="tns:RateQuoteSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuote">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuote" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:RateQuoteAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccount">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuoteByAccount" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal">
      <soap:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
        <soap:header message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="RateQuoteSoap12" type="tns:RateQuoteSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuote">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuote" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:RateQuoteAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccount">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuoteByAccount" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="https://webservices.example.com/ratequote/RateQuoteByAccountByTerminal" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
        <soap12:header message="tns:RateQuoteByAccountByTerminalAuthenticationHeader" part="AuthenticationHeader" use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="RateQuote">
    <wsdl:port name="RateQuoteSoap" binding="tns:RateQuoteSoap">
      <soap:address location="https://webservices.example.com/rating/ratequote.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="RateQuoteSoap12" binding="tns:RateQuoteSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="https://webservices.example.com/rating/ratequote.asmx"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: It looks like it wants `QuoteRequest` to be an object, not an array. Try to make it an `stdClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The line the error is talking about doesn't seem to even exist in the code you posted, so it's not that piece of code.

I don't know what SoapClient::RateQuote() does, but it sounds like it takes the values you pass into the array, and assign those values to the properties of an object. (The error messages use of the term "property" specifically indicates an object/class variable, not simply an array key.) So it sounds like the QuoteRequest object doesn't have a $Pieces property (class variable).

This is a bit of a SWAG in the dark.

One other thing that I see is that in the WSDL, Pieces is an int, but you're passing in a string. In PHP it usually doesn't matter, but it does matter internally, and might be clashing with what SoapClient expects to have. Try passing that `"Pieces" => '0'` as just `"Pieces" => 0` .

Comment: I had comments and extraneous lines like `echo "<PRE>";` that I removed.  That is why the line numbers do not match and why I included the specific offending code that it points to.  I also did try ` => '0'` and `=> 0`.  Also the SoapClient::RateQuote() is (or I assume based on samples) another way of doing `$return = $client->__soapCall('RateQuote', array('request'=>$params));`